# No migrations to apply but no such table after migration

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I created Django model named Comparison and also generated migration file.

When I run migrate, Django says there is no migrations to apply however when I access the model page form admin site it shows 'no such table' error.  I browsed DB using 'DB Browser for SQLite' and there seem to be no table named comparison.

I probable have made then same named model before and deleted but it should be deleted and is deleted as I browse DB.

I'm stuck since usually when django shows no migrations to apply, I should fix it by deleting existing table with the name but there aren't any table to delete.

```
from django.db import models
from apps.tag.models import Tag

class Comparison(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Tag, null = True, blank = False, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'comparisons')
```

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('tag', '0013_auto_20201010_2219'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Comparison',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('topic', models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='comparisons', to='tag.Tag')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: did you add the app's name in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Yes I added the app to INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Try python manage.py migrate <APP_NAME> <MIGRATION_NUMBER_PREFIX>

MIGRATION_NUMBER_PREFIX - name of this migration file

Comment: I tried specifying the migration file but it still claims there is no migrations to apply.  I tried further and I seems like first migration file is ignored and if I make second migration file with other model it worked.

Comment: If you are able to browse tables, check table: django_migrations and see if the first migration name is there or not. if you see the first migration name then delete and run migrate command(but this is an unethical way)

Comment: I gave up perfect solution but did some work around. I just used different name for model and it worked fine. But thanks for your helps.

Comment: Yeh, that works too.